# Bash script and netctl

Tags: bash, networking, profile, archlinux

I'm trying to create a little script to automate the wlan-login. (I don't have a GUI or something for my network-management.)

Here is the problem:

The command "netctl list" usually lists all available (wireless) profiles. It works fine if I just drop the command in a terminal, but used in a script it returns really weird stuff. The output is the same as I'd combine the output of "ls" and "netctl list". Please note the specific codepart is below:

```
PS3="Choose a profile: "
prof_select=$(netctl list)

select profile in $prof_select
do

    echo "[+] Stopping all other profiles..."
    `netctl stop-all`
    wait
    echo "[+] Starting profile" $profile "..."
    `netctl start $profile`
    wait
    break  
done
```

FYI: I'm using Arch Linux. I have (for wireless connections) iw and wpa_supplicant installed, and on the manual way everything works fine.

The complete script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Select IF
PS3='Choose an interface: ' 
if_select=$(ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

select interface in $if_select
do
    echo "[+] Shutting down IF"
    # Shut down the interface
    ip link set dev $interface down
    # Break, otherwise endless loop
    break  
done

# Spoof MAC?
read -p "[?] Want a spoofed MAC? (Y/N)" answer  

while true
do
    case $answer in 
        [yY]* ) 
            echo "[+] Current MAC: " $(ip link show $interface | grep link/ether)
            wait
            ip link set dev $interface address 16:60:51:50:DB:82
            wait
            echo "[+] New MAC: " $(ip link show $interface | grep link/ether)
            break;; 

        [nN]* ) break;;     

        *)  echo "[-] This might be an answer, but not the one im looking for :/"; exit 0;;

    esac
done

IFS=$'\t *' read -r -a profiles < <(netctl list)
#prof_select=$(netctl list)

select profile in "${profiles[@]}"
do

    echo "[+] Stopping all other profiles..."
    netctl stop-all
    wait
    echo "[+] Starting profile" $profile "..."
    netctl start $profile
    wait
    break  
done

exit 0
```

Comment: The "really weird stuff" is very hard to troubleshoot without an example.  Do you mean it contains screen control codes?  Can you post an example?  Maybe the output of `netctl list | cat -v`?

Comment: There's a lot that's wrong here. Putting a command in backticks for no good reason, for example, is basically *always* the wrong thing. And run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before posting it here as a matter of habit.

Comment: Unless `netctl stop-all` and `netctl start` output Bash commands you can execute, putting them in backticks is not only wrong, but potentially dangerous.

Comment: ...and treating a string (such as the one you have captured in the variable named `prof_select`) as if it were a list or array is... very much less than ideal as well.

Comment: anyhow, "really weird stuff" isn't enough to go on. We need **exact** error messages and output -- or ideally, a script we can run ourselves to produce the same behavior, with everything unrelated to that behavior removed; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @tripleee, ...btw, can't say I'm running the same version of netctl the OP is, or that pertinent configuration is identical, but I don't have any terminal control sequences when output is not to a TTY invoking it here.

Comment: I'll update my post and give you the complete script. I know i made mistakes, this is my FIRST try with bash-stuff. Thanks for the informations so far :)

Comment: @Simulacrum, the question isn't just the **printed** output, but the nonprintable characters included to control colorization or the like.

Comment: Sounds like the backticks are the problem then, and it outputs something with an asterisk.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.  Remember http://shellcheck.net/ for the future.

Comment: @Simulacrum, consider `IFS=$'\n\t *' read -r -a profiles < <(netctl list)`, and `select profile in "${profiles[@]}"` -- no glob expansion happening in the list part that way. And yes, ditch the backticks.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the suggest, im using it right now.

Comment: I removed the backticks, but it doesnt work... netctl list still give me the content of the CWD + the network profiles. Updated code in the main post.

Comment: I applied @CharlesDuffy suggestions and it seem to work. Furthermore, i asked a friend to test the script. It works for him, so i have probably a "bigger" problem. Thanks to all of you. :)

Comment: Hmm. Oops, that should have been `IFS=$'\n\t *' read -r -d '' -a profiles < <(netctl list) || (( ${#profiles[@]} ))` to be able to read more than one line. But I'm glad this has been helpful. :)

Comment: (btw, the reason I'm not writing up an answer here is because I'm sitting on the close vote, until/unless this is rewritten to be a reasonably-scoped question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Inasmuch as it's no longer a question the OP cares about, and *hasn't* been distilled down to a minimal essence likely to be helpful to other people, perhaps the OP might want to delete it?)